# Which port is used for receiving email?Is it the same port for sending email SMTP (25)?

Tags: email, network-protocols

I just noticed my ISP blocked both direction for port 25. Does that mean port 25 is for both sending or receiving email? ( As email servers , transferring emails in-between) among Used to think it is for sending only.

Comment: how did you came to conclusion port 25 is blocked by your ISP?

Answer (score 1):

Port 25 is for sending and receiving email *between servers.* For mail on a client like Thunderbird, for the most part you'll be using 110 or 143 (POP3 or IMAP) to receive email, and port 465 or 587 (SMTP over TLS-on-connect or SMTP with STARTTLS).

Comment: @NathaneilCapital If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept.

Comment: More specifically, port 25 is the default port for SMTP.

Comment: @Keltari For servers, yes, but most mail clients I've seen default to 587.